# Selenium followers automation

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

I tried to automate the following in instagram but the process worked only for entering to my instagram account without pressing on any follow suggestion please help me to automate the following.

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

browser =  webdriver.Chrome()
#open instagram
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")  
#wait for 3 sec to fully load the page
time.sleep (3)

#identify user field and send username
username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']").send_keys("username")
#identify password field and send password
password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']").send_keys("password")
#find and click submit
login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()
#click on notNow button
time.sleep(2)
notNowButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(
    lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not now"]'))
notNowButton.click()

#loop
for i in range (5):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="f25ff3bf4393664"]/button/div').click()
    browser.refresh()
    time.sleep(3)
```

by the line "`browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="f25ff3bf4393664"]/button/div').click()`" I expected the program to click on the following button beside the accounts suggested on the Instagram account but nothing happens

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Please see [ask].

Comment: I tried to automate the pressing on the instagram following suggestions feed. the login to the account  succeed but I got these Errors: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_css_selector is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector) instead

Comment: I expected the program to click on the following button beside the accounts suggested on the Instagram account but nothing happens

Comment: And I also got these Errors: File "user\PycharmProjects\mino\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="f9f85812015914"]/button/div').click()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\mino\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 526, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

Comment: File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\mino\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\mino\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\mino\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify. Code and errors are hard to read in comments. [Edit] your question instead. (Sorry, I should have mentioned that.)